# Disable Linux Mint system start sound?

Tags: linux, gnome, linux-mint

How do I disable the system start sound in Linux Mint. I am talking about when you are presented with the login screen. There is a sound that accompanies the login screen. I tried to access a program called Sound after logging in, but it says that it cannot be found.

Comment: yes this sound is abnormally loud

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the requested [instructions](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-linux-mint-after-installation.htm#Disable-Change-Login-Sound) to disable the sound

in short To disable the login sound :

```
Go to Menu > Applications > Preferences > Startup Applications.
Under the "Startup Programs" tab, untick "GNOME Login Sound"
Click Close
```

Gnome3 try

Run `gnome-session-properties` there is an option called `GNOME Login Sound`

Comment: I'm using GNOME3, but I opened up gnome-session-properties, which are the instructions for disabling sound on gnome3, but nothing called GNOME Login Sound was listed.

Comment: i've update my post for gnome3

Answer (score 1):

These settings didn't work for my LMDE. To permenantly fix this on gnome versions and mate desktops, install 'gnome-alsamixer' and mute beep settings.

This worked for me when disabling of random sound settings and blacklisting module didnt help.