# How to disable login and other system sounds in Linux Mint 19.1

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

This question has been asked before on this forum for an earlier version of Mint  [Disable Linux Mint system start sound?](https://superuser.com/questions/424230/disable-linux-mint-system-start-sound)

In the 19.1 Cinnamon startup menu there is no option "GNOME Login Sound". I've checked elsewhere but have not found any way to disable login or other sounds, like the incredibly harsh one accompanying workspace selection. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may vary a little depending on which desktop environment you're using.  In Cinnamon:

- Open the System Settings Control Center.
- Under `Hardware`, open `Sound`.
- Click on the `Sounds` tab at the top.
- There, you can adjust the volume for system sounds in general, and toggle specific sounds on and off.

Comment: thanks very much altho I'm a LInux Mint noobie, I should have seen that :)